# net::ERR_CACHE_READ_FAILURE in Electron app

Tags: electron

I occasionally (~ 1 out of 30 times) get a `net::ERR_CACHE_READ_FAILURE` in Chrome dev tools when loading my Electron app. I can't track down a reason for the error and I can't reproduce it consistently. Has anyone run into this problem before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run multiple instances of your app, the first instance might lock the cache, which will prevent another instance from reading the cache.

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7246#issuecomment-248519152) Github issue:

> You should not run multiple instances of the same app at the same time, for certain operations global locks are applied. In your case the cache database is locked by one instance and all other instances will fail to read cache.

You can use the [`app.requestSingleInstanceLock()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#apprequestsingleinstancelock) API to prevent multiple instances of your application from running if that is appropriate for you.

Comment: For anyone else with this issue, this was happening to me because I would often be using the production version of our app while also working the dev version, so there were two versions open.